# Androidでユーザー設定の文字サイズに影響されず固定サイズにする方法

Tags: android, monaca, css

**Android**は文字サイズをユーザー側で少・中・大・特大に変更できる機能がありますが、
Monacaでアプリを開発する際に**ユーザー設定の文字サイズに影響されず固定サイズ**にする方法はありますか？

**【開発】**
Monaca

**【実機】**
Android 4.4.4

**【試した方法】**
htmlに以下記述

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

cssに以下記述

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

普段はionicを使用しておりMonocaは使ってないのですが、同じCordovaなので、このプラグインが使えると思います。
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-mobile-accessibility

端末のアクセシビリティの情報を透過的に取得できるプラグインです。
実装例は以下URLに記載されています。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27003829/phonegap-ignore-font-size-display-setting-on-android
ionic/AngularJSの例ですが、AngularJS+Onsen UIなら`ons.ready`に記述すればよいかと思います。

それから、本件とはあまり関係ないかもしれませんが、`target-densitydpi=device-dpi`は色々とクセがあるようです（ググると色々出てきます）。
ご承知の上かもしれませんが、念のため・・・

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました。
諸事情でなるべくプラグインを使わずにと試行錯誤していてお礼が遅れました。ありがとうございました。
やっぱり使わないと厳しいみたいですね。